# Accessing different elements in list

Tags: java

New and learning here. So lets say i have multiple PhoneCalls in this list, im just trying to figure out how the easiest way to access lets say the 7th phone calls *number* how would i go about that? .get() gives me all of the information but i just want part of it.

```
class PhoneCall{
 String name;
 String number;
 String type;
 String date;
 PhoneCall(String name, String number, String type, String date)
 {
     this.name = name;
     this.number = number;
     this.type = type;
     this.date = date;
 }
```

`ArrayList<PhoneCall> list = new ArrayList<PhoneCall>();`

`list.add(new PhoneCall(name,number,type,date));`

Comment: `list.get(6).number`

Comment: Forget the list for a second. How do you get information from any singular `PhoneCall` object?

Comment: Thank you shmosel, didn't know you could do that.
@cricket list.get(i)

Comment: mod of schmosels: `list.get(6).getNumber()` because you should use getters

Comment: Are you accessing this data from the same package as your `PhoneCall` class?

Comment: Even better jack ty @PM77-1 Negatory.

Comment: No, you said that gets you the full information. If I asked you to get the `type` of a `new PhoneCall()`, what would you do? That is your question, and really it isn't about the list at all

Comment: list.get(i).type?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `get` method:

```
list.get(index);
```

If you don't want the whole `PhoneCall` object, only get a certain field from the object:

```
list.get(index).field;
```

So, to answer your question, do:

```
list.get(6).number;
```